# Testing independence hypothesis in logistic regression

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, logistic, independence

One of the primary hypotheses in logistic regression theory is the independence of observations. Once the model is fitted to the data (using likelihood maximization procedure for example), I am wondering, is it possible to test independence of the residuals in logistic regression?  (as is common practice in time series area)

In my opinion, the independence hypothesis is material in the theory as the likelihood function is based on that fact. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to find something about this and I was wondering why.

Comment: Hi, true indeed, is it possible for a moderator to move the question from here to the cross-validated forum ?

Comment: I have flagged it. They will respond soon. You can copy and then delete it as well.

Comment: *Residuals* are not independent in logistic regression or even in linear regression. Why would you test something you already know the answer to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You have to be somewhat careful about how to define the residuals. To be concrete, suppose we have a time series. Let the binary outcome be $y_t$ and the vector of regressors be $x_t$. An obvious thing is to take $\hat{\epsilon}_t = y_t - \frac{e^{x_t \hat{\beta}} } {1+e^{x_t \hat{\beta}} }$. However, these residuals are heteroskedastic, which makes their asymptotic distribution under the null slightly more complicated. It's easier to work with 
$\tilde{\epsilon}_t = \frac{\hat{\epsilon}_t}{ \sqrt{ (\frac{e^{x_t \hat{\beta}} } {1+e^{x_t \hat{\beta}} })(1 - \frac{e^{x_t \hat{\beta}} } {1+e^{x_t \hat{\beta}} }) } } $. [Hsiao, Pesaran, and Pick (2007)](http://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=982629) discuss this approach for testing independence in panel data.

Alternatively, you can work with what [Gorieroux, Monfort, and Trognon (1985)](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3532187) call generalized residuals, $\hat{\varepsilon}_t = \mathrm{E}[y_t^\ast - x_t \beta | y_t, x_t] = y_t - \frac{1}{1+e^{-x_t\beta}}$. 
They show that $S_1 = \frac{(\sum_{t=2}^T \hat{\varepsilon}_t \hat{\varepsilon}_{t-1})^2}{\sum_{t=2}^T \hat{\varepsilon}_t^2 \hat{\varepsilon}_{t-1}^2} \overset{d}{\rightarrow} \chi^2_1$. They also discuss how $S_1$ relates to the usual Durbin-Watson test statistic.

Comment: Hi, thank's for the reference my problem is that I can't index my residuals with respect to time. All my covariates and my response variable are unrelated to an order. At a moment I was considering the idea to draw uniformly an order and test the resulting ordered output as in a time series framework. I think taking randomly any ordering should not affect the hypothesis $H_0$ but I don't know if this approach is correct or if any asymptotic results exist on the distribution of such a statistic in this context. Best regards

Comment: I don't think testing for independence is possible unless you have some idea of what form the dependence might take (time series, panel, spatial, etc). If you randomly assign an order and test for independence once, then the test will have correct size, but it generally will not have any power. For example, if you take a stationary time series with dependence and then randomly reorder it, the observations will become independent asymptotically, and the test with random ordering has asymptotic power equal to size.